# How do you write a pygame function that draws...2

Tags: python, pygame

I have made up short script to show my problem:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 525
COLOR = (255, 255, 255)
COLOR2 = (230, 230, 255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(COLOR)

import pygame.font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 45, bold = True, italic = False)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR2, pygame.Rect(65, 660, 400, 100))

img = font.render('AAAAAA', True, (0, 0, 0)) # BLACK FONT 
screen.blit(img, (150, 685))

def draw_rect(screen, COLOR2, Rect ):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR2, Rect = pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))
    
# draw_rect(screen, COLOR2, pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))    

pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR2, pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))
  

pygame.display.update()
```

This runs. If you uncomment the draw_rect line and comment the next line (pygame.draw.rect..., it gives error messages about argument 3.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
def draw_rect(screen=screen, color=COLOR2, Rect=pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100)):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, Rect)
```

Adding these default argument values will allow the function to draw a default rectangle without any arguments. If `screen` and `COLOR2` weren't the values you wanted to use, you could pass your own.

The way you had it written before, the `Rect` in the function signature was interfering with your attempt to define `Rect` in the body of the function. You were essentially writing

```
pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100) = pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100)
```

which is illegal - a `pygame.Rect` object can't be assigned to.